Weird behavior of class using const. references
I wanted to have a class variable that has public readonly access and can be edited in a private context.
In this  previous Stackoverflow Question it was described to use const references.
However for me this leads to strange behaviour.
    class Vec3 {
    public:
        double x, y, z;
        Vec3(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
        Vec3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    };
    
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vec3& a) {
        os << "(" << a.x << ", " << a.y << ", " << a.z << ")";
        return os;
    }
    
    class Triangle3 {
    private:
        Vec3 _a, _b, _c;
    public:
        Triangle3(const Vec3& a, const Vec3& b, const Vec3& c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {}
        Triangle3() : _a(Vec3()), _b(Vec3()), _c(Vec3()) {}
    
        const Vec3& a = _a;
        const Vec3& b = _b;
        const Vec3& c = _c;
    };
    
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Triangle3& a) {
        os << "(" << a.a.x << ", " << a.a.y << ", " << a.a.z << "), ";
        os << "(" << a.b.x << ", " << a.b.y << ", " << a.b.z << "), ";
        os << "(" << a.c.x << ", " << a.c.y << ", " << a.c.z << ")";
        return os;
    }

    class Mesh {
    public:
        std::vector<Triangle3> triangles;
        Mesh(std::vector<Triangle3> triangles) : triangles(triangles) {}
        Mesh() {}
    };

    int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        std::vector<Triangle3> triangles;
        int N = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                triangles.push_back(Triangle3(Vec3(i, i, i), Vec3(i, i, i), Vec3(i, i, i)));
        }
        std::cout << "Triangle 0: " << triangles[0] << std::endl;
        Mesh mesh(triangles);
        std::cout << "Triangle 0: " << mesh.triangles[0] << std::endl;
    }

This program outputs:
Triangle 0: (9, 9, 9), (9, 9, 9), (9, 9, 9)
Triangle 0: (4.03359e-316, 4.03364e-316, 4.03364e-316), (9, 9, 9), (9, 9, 9)

valgrind --leak-check=full -s returns with no errors or warnings.
Then rewriting the Triangle3 class to not use const references:
class Triangle3 {
private:
public:
    Vec3 a, b, c;
    Triangle3(const Vec3& a, const Vec3& b, const Vec3& c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
    Triangle3() : a(Vec3()), b(Vec3()), c(Vec3()) {}
};

This returns the correct results:
Triangle 0: (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)
Triangle 0: (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)

Anybody know what is causing this?
I heavily suspect the const references are not working as advertised but why?

Consider what happens when you copy a Triangle. What is a referencing at that point?

Even if you would get the references to work you are going to shoot yourself in the foot. The moment you add one more triangle to your vector ALL references (into the vector) will be invalidated. And then all your Triangles will be useless, you will have to find another way to model your triangles (e.g. use indices).

Really think of references as "views" on data. The moment that data moves in memory (E.g. your vector of Vec3, or Triangle resizes) those views become invalid. So the only safe way to use references is that when by design you can guarantee the referenced objects don't move in memory you can hold on to them. In all other cases do not let them survive past the end of a scope.

https://godbolt.org/z/YnEY6on9M

... to use const references.  Use public accessor methods.

Thank you all. It seems like I completely overlooked the fact that the default copy constructor will also copy the references for a,b,c. This then leads to references to invalid elements.

The issue here is that when you are push_backing to the vector, you are making a copy of the Triangle. When this happens, the references are still referencing the elements of the original Triangle, which then gets destroyed, and you are then referencing invalid elements. This is Undefined Behaviour. This also happens (again) whenever the vector needs to resize.
Adding a copy-constructor will solve the issue:
Triangle3( const Triangle3& o ) : _a(o.a), _b(o.b), _c(o.c){}

However, this is still a rather dangerous approach, and you also need operator=.

Ok thanks that makes sense. I thought that if a new Triangle3 gets created the references are set to the new _a,_b,_c. Then these are set to the new values and everything works out.
Seems like I forgot to think about the default copy constructor also setting the const references to the old Triangle. Makes sense
